# Need Greatest common divisor explaination

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, natural-numbers

In the book the problem says:
What is the GCD of two natural numbers m and n if after increasing the number m by 6 the GCD of two numbers increased 9 times.

And the solution it gives is 2,3 or 6.
Can someone explain how is it. And what values of m and n satisfy the equation. I can't find any. May be i couldn't understand the question or the book is miss printed. Idk. Please help me understand this with some examples. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$\gcd(a;b)=d$ and $\gcd(a;b+6)=9d$ so $$d\mid b+6\mbox{ and }d\mid b\Rightarrow d\mid 6$$

Assume $d=1$. Then $a$ and $b$ are coprime and $a=9x$ and $b+6=9y$ with coprime $x,y$. This implies $3\mid a$ and $3\mid b$ so contradiction.

So $d\mid 6$ and $d\neq 1$, so $d$ can only be $2,3$ or $6$

Comment: Can u give me one example of m, n and d values where this equation is true

Comment: I edited to include every explanation

Comment: $m=21$ , $n=27$ with $d=3$ and $m=48$ , $n=54$ with $d=6$

Comment: $d$ cannot be $2$ since $3$ has to divide $m+6$ and $n$ and therefore $3$ divides $d$

Comment: In above answer he said d can be 2 also.

Comment: Yes, d cannot be $2$ but I left that out. You had to prove $d$ can be only $2,3$ or $6$. The fact that it CAN BE doesn't mean it WILL BE.

Comment: @Asim I added a proof of a generalization which makes it clear why $\ 3\mid (m,n)\mid 6\ \ $

Comment: @Vlad would u plz explain this line : Assume d=1. Then a and b are coprime and a=9x and b+6=9y with coprime x,y. This implies 3∣a and 3∣b so contradiction.  Sorry but didnt get the idea why 3 has to divide a and b from the above equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\, $ By below, with $\,j=2,\, k = 3\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid (m,n)\mid 6$

**Lemma** $\, \ k,(m,n)\mid (m,\:\!n\!+\!jk)\!\iff\! k\mid (m,n)\mid jk$

**Proof** $\,\ $ Note $\ (m,n)\mid n,\,n\!+\!jk\,\iff (m,n)\mid jk,\, $

and $\ k\mid m,n\!+\!jk\! \iff k\mid m,n\iff k\mid (m,n)$